# how do i access the list of people subscribed to a channel?

Tags: javascript, web, javascript-objects, pusher

so i'm trying to iterate through the members of a pusher presence channel,
the pusher documentation says this can be done by

`pusher.members.each(function (member){`

`console.log(member);` 


`});`

but i'm getting an error in my console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'each' of undefined(…)
```

i even tried typing `presence.members.count` in the console, it returns the same error as above. the pusher js library is properly linked and the loop is triggered when the subscription to the presence channel is successful.

please what am i doing wrong? and why am i getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

`members` is an attribute of your presence channel object, not the `Pusher` object.

You need to set up a subscription, like so `var presenceChannel = pusher.subscribe(presenceChannelName);`. Then you can access `presenceChannel.members`.

Comment: I did subscribe to a presence channel with the variable name pusher

Comment: @SeunLanLege can you post the code of where you instantiate the Pusher object, and subscribe to the presence channel?